# Problemas con equivalencia de Unidades de Medida Productos

Tags: php, mysql

estoy desarrollando un sistema de almacén y tengo un problema que no se como solucionarlo. Tengo un cliente que compra a su proveedor por cajas chocolate Triángulo, cada caja trae 24 display, y cada display contiene 22 unidades. Mi cliente puede vender por cajas, por displays y por unidades, eso depende de como venda sus productos y así sucesivamente muchos productos como gaseosas, jabones, etc.

Recurro a ustedes si me pueden orientar como desarrollar en mi sistema esta funcionalidad ya que actualmente solo me permite vender por unidades y en mi almacén todo está en unidades también. Ejemplo, si quieren vender una caja de Chocolate Triángulo, agregan 528 unidades y descuenta en mi almacén las 528 unidades vendidas, pero quieren que en la parte de venta ya no se agregue 528 unidades si no 1 caja si el cliente compra por caja, si pide por display, si pide por unidad, vender por unidad.

Alguna sugerencia como podría solucionar este inconveniente?.

Comment: ¿Lo que dices: *1 caja=24 display; 1 display=22 unidades; 1 unidad = 1 unidad*  se aplica **en todos los casos**?  Si es así, lo puedes seguir manejando por unidades y sólo en la vista aplicas alguna lógica para que te convierta según las cantidades vendidas. Piensa en casos más complicados como: *una caja y media; 3 display y 2 unidades; etc*

Comment: @A.Cedano justamente eso ocurreo, cuando vende por cajas agregan 1 display de bonificación, o en todo caso 1 unidad de bonificación.